# Async Python. How do long asyncio.sleep intervals affect performance and memory consumption?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, sleep

Let's say I want to put a coroutine to sleep for several hours. Here's an abstract code sample:

```
while True:
    if need_to_sleep():
        await asyncio.sleep(14400)
    ...
```

How would sleeping a coroutine for hours affect memory consumption or CPU usage?